# Is it possible to populate directives in a page dynamically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a list directive selectors in an array I need to populate them dynamically in a page at runtime how do I proceed I am using angularjs 1.5.8

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, could you share with us and explain what is not working?

Comment: What is the exact problem..  Share your code

Comment: I tried putting all the directives in that page and just hide or showed them based on the array values. But it is really slow

Comment: As the number of directives get huge it is not good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use $compile service to do that. For example, you have the following array of directives:

```
var myDirectives = [
     "<my-app-directive-one></my-app-directive-one>",
     "<my-app-directive-two></my-app-directive-two>",
     "<my-app-directive-three></my-app-directive-three>"
];
```

Then you can compile them individually or in a loop and insert to you html like this:

```
TestDirective.$inject = ["$compile"];
function TestDirective($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        link: link
    };

    function link(scope, element) {
        element.append($compile(myDirectives[0])(scope));
    }
}
```

I used the scope of a parent directive (used as a directive sandbox), but you can create a child scope (scope.$new()) or an isolated scope (scope.$new(false)) for it.

If you array looks like this:

```
var myDirectives = ["my-app-directive-one", "my-app-directive-two"];
```

then you can simply do the following transformation:

```
myDirectives = myDirectives.map(
    function(directive) {
        return "<" + directive + "></" + directive + ">";
    }
);
```

**Simpler solution**

You can just use ng-if instead of ng-show, if you can place all the directives on the same page before runtime. It will solve you perfomance issues, since ng-if removes all the watchers when destroying a directive.